# unity c# OnCollisionEnter2D() Not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I can't get a collision detection to work between and Enemy object and a Projectile object. I tried looking online for anyone else having similar problems, but haven't been able to find anything that relates to the problems I'm having.

I'm not getting any errors in the console or warnings.

In my c# code that's a component to and object with a Rigidbody2D and CircleCollider2D I have

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    print("collision");
    if (collision.transform.tag == "Projectile") {
        print("Collision with Projectile");
    }
}
```

Not getting collision prints from the code above to print to console.

I have another object that has RigidBody2D and CircleCollider2D as well. It also has the tag "Projectile". When the collider areas overlap with each other nothing happens.

Enemy: RigidBody2D, CircleCollider2D, C# code above.

Enemy:Tag: "Projectile", RigidBody2D, CircleCollider2D: IsTrigger - true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your rigidbody properties?

I know some of the properties that you can change on that effect the way collisions work, try turning off simulated if that one is on for a start.

Answer (score 0):

You have isTrigger checked in collider component. OnCollisionEnter doesn't work when trigger is enabled. There's another function OnTriggerEnter if you want to use trigger.
[OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)

[OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

Don't confuse these two.

Comment: I have tried with and without Trigger on both. I just tried OnTriggerEnter2D Nothing changed.

Comment: Nevermind I figure it out, I just forgot to set simulated to true on the Projectile's rigidbody

Comment: Glad you figured it out